# Pass radio values without knowing the unique radio names

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I created a list of radio groups and attached them to a product category. So what am doing is checking the groups that the category is meant to have then am going to then pick up the radio values in those groups available to the category and display them to the user to fill.

The next thing is I want to pass them to my ajax function which will then inject it into database. The problem is I can't get the unique name of the radio input in my ajax since I am loading it from the database.

```
<?php $notarray = DataDB::getInstance()->select_from_where('pro_print_group','product_category_id',$cat);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($notarray)) {?>
     <div class="col-sm-12">
      <label for="quantity"><?php echo DataDB::getInstance()->get_name_from_id('group_n','print_type_group','print_type_group_id',$row['print_type_group_id']); ?></label>
      <div class="printd-group">
       <?php
       $not = DataDB::getInstance()->select_from_where('print_type','print_type_group_id',$row['print_type_group_id']);
       foreach($not as $ow):?>
        <label class="printd">                          
            <input name="prind<?php echo $row['print_type_group_id'] ;?>[]" id="prind<?php echo $row['print_type_group_id'] ;?>[]" value="<?php echo $ow['print_type_id'] ;?>" checked="" type="radio" class="name" data-price="0"> <?php echo $ow['name'] ;?>
        </label>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
      </div>
      </div>
      <?php } ?>
```

**Ajax Function**
when form is submitted i call this function

```
function testpr() {
     document.getElementById("load").style.display = "block";
    var track = 'YU6758990';
    var printd = $('#printd').val();
     $.ajax({
         type: 'post',
         url: 'frverify.php',
        data: "track=" + track + "&printd=" + printd + "&ins=testp",
             success: function(data)
        {   
            document.getElementById("load").style.display = "none";
            jQuery('#get_prresult').html(data).show();
            scroll_to('#messs');

        }
    });
}
```

**PHP function**
The ajax function then passes it to this php function where I am to receive the post request which in return inserts the selected radio values to the database and then returns the response back to my front end

```
function test(){
    $track = $_POST['tack'];
    $printd = $_POST['printd'];

    echo DataDB::getInstance()->testp($track,$printd);              

 }
```

Comment: I can't find an element in your code with the attribute `id='printd'`.

Comment: missed it while putting it here@PeterM

Comment: Still `id="prind<?php echo $row['print_type_group_id'] ;?>[]"` can not be selected with just `$('#printd')`

Comment: ho do i select it then, thats my problem. i cant transfer this data to my ajax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that there are more then one radiobutton generated, if that's the case you could try something like this.

```
<input name="printd[<?php echo $row['print_type_group_id'] ;?>]" id="<?php echo $row['print_type_group_id'] ;?>" value="<?php echo $ow['print_type_id'] ;?>" checked="" type="radio" class="name" data-price="0"> <?php echo $ow['name'] ;?>
```

Then in your Javascript change the way you retrieve the values of your form by using [serialize](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/).

```
data: "track=" + track + "&" + $('form#id.selector').serialize() + "&ins=testp"
```

Then inside your PHP script iterate trough the values with some sort of foreach loop

```
function test(){
    $track = $_POST['tack'];
    foreach($_POST['printd'] as $key => $value){
        //$key => print_type_group_id
        //$value => print_type_id
    }
    echo DataDB::getInstance()->testp($track,$printd);              
}
```

Not sure what you want to do with the data and what it is you actually need but this should send you in the right direction.

Comment: the ajax is not passing the printd values

Comment: Did you change `$('form#id.selector')` into something that suits your situation?